# How to request stenographic transcripts of psychiatric commitment proceedings under NYMHL from Westchester County Court's archive?

Tags: new-york-state, court-records, mental-health

What is the process for obtaining transcripts of the judicial involuntary psychiatric commitment hearing and what form exactly would they be provided in?

Comment: White Plains is a city (so has a City Court) the County Court is Westchester. http://ww2.nycourts.gov/courts/9jd/westchester/index.shtml

Comment: @Rick Okay, and are mental hygiene proceedings heard in the city court or county court then?